# Are there any tools for converting Managed C++ to C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++, code-conversion

We have an old project written using Managed C++ syntax. I would like to propose to the team a reasonably pain-free (I don't mind some level of human interaction, I think I'm realistic in my expectations that we'll still have to do some work by hand) method of updating the existing code to C++/CLI syntax so that we can also add XML documentation (the project is a library into other projects and having documentation would be immensely useful).

So, are there any good tools out there to help with this? Or is it just a case of switching to the new C++/CLI syntax compiler and fixing errors as we go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a [tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a3581805-1af2-4c34-9d0e-6029cc078441&displaylang=en) that will help a little. [Visual c++ blog post about it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2006/12/08/managed-extensions-for-c-to-c-cli-conversion-tool.aspx)  Here are a couple other resources I found useful when I made our switch
[C++/CLI Migration Primer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms235289.aspx)
[Managed Extensions for C++ Syntax Upgrade Checklist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/b23b94s7.aspx)

The Microsoft tool is just a start. there were many files that it could not convert.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I found the [migration tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a3581805-1af2-4c34-9d0e-6029cc078441&displaylang=en) from Microsoft to be two steps away from useless. However, there is the [C++/CLI disassembler](http://www.sandpapersoftware.com/Main/Reflector.html) for [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm), which has proved a lot more useful.

This isn't perfect as comments get lost, but I've found that re-adding the comments is much easier than trying to hand-convert the majority of the code.